# Is there a way to add an anchor tag to an insertCell function?

Tags: javascript, html

for example, I want to add input from a textbox to the row

JS

```
var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
var cel0 = newRow.insertCell(0);
cel0.innerHTML = id;
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="id">
```

is there a way to assign an anchor tag to it once inserted in the table so that I could open a modal with it?

Answer (score 2):

This should work (if I understand your question correctly):

```
cel0.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"test()\">Click me!</a>"
```

```js
var tr = document.getElementById("tr");

function addcell()
{
    var cel0 = tr.insertCell(0);
    cel0.innerHTML = "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"test()\">Click me!</a>";

}

function test()
{
    alert("Don't hit me!");
}

addcell();
addcell();
addcell();
addcell();
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
<tr id="tr">

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks! sorry but I forgot to add that I am getting the input from a textbox so I need to put a variable inside the tag so that it gets the value of the textbox and gives it an anchor tag for the modal. how would I rephrase the snippet?